# Deriving physics result for definite integral involving Dirac delta function

Tags: real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals, physics, dirac-delta

I'm reading electrodynamics physics notes that describe a cavity of length $L$. The cavity is said to lie along the $z$-axis from $-L$ to $0$. There is a reflective mirror at $z = 0$, represented by an increase in the dielectric permittivity $\epsilon(z) = \epsilon_0[1 + \Lambda \delta(z)]$, where $\Lambda$ is a parameter that determines the reflectivity of the window.

To find how the reflective mirror affects the electromagnetic field, the notes integrate Maxwell's equations across the mirror (where there is an increase in the dielectric permittivity). The notes state that, from

$$\dfrac{\partial{E}(z, t)}{\partial{z}} = - \mu_0 \dot{H}(z, t),$$

we get that

$$E(0^+, t) = E(0^-, t),$$

and from

$$-\dfrac{\partial{H}(z, t)}{\partial{z}} = \epsilon(z) \dot{E}(z, t),$$

we get that there is a discontinuity of

$$H(0^+, t) - H(0^-, t) = - \Lambda \epsilon_0 \dot{E}(0, t)$$

Attempting to calculate this last one, I have

$$\begin{align} \int_{0^+}^{0^-} -\dfrac{\partial{H}(z, t)}{\partial{z}} \ dz = \int_{0^+}^{0^-} \epsilon(z) \dot{E}(z, t) \ dz \\ \Rightarrow -[H(0^-, t) - H(0^+, t)] = [\Lambda \epsilon_0 \dot{E}(z, t)]^{0^-}_{0^+} - \int_{0^+}^{0^-} \Lambda \epsilon_0 \dfrac{\partial{\dot{E}}(z, t)}{\partial{z}} \ dz \end{align}$$

I got $-[H(0^-, t) - H(0^+, t)]$ by the fundamental theorem of calculus, and I got $[\Lambda \epsilon_0 \dot{E}(z, t)]^{0^-}_{0^+} - \int_{0^+}^{0^-} \Lambda \epsilon_0 \dfrac{\partial{\dot{E}}(z, t)}{\partial{z}} \ dz$ by integration by parts, where $\int_{0^+}^{0^-} \epsilon_0[1 + \Lambda \delta(z)] = \Lambda \epsilon_0$, since, as I understand the [Dirac delta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function#Definitions), $\int_{0^+}^{0^-} \delta(z) \ dz = 1$.

Continuing, I got that

$$\begin{align} [\Lambda \epsilon_0 \dot{E}(z, t)]^{0^-}_{0^+} - \int_{0^+}^{0^-} \Lambda \epsilon_0 \dfrac{\partial{\dot{E}}(z, t)}{\partial{z}} \ dz = \Lambda \epsilon_0 [\dot{E}(0^-, t) - \dot{E}(0^+, t)] - \Lambda \epsilon_0 \int_{0^+}^{0^-} \dfrac{\partial{\dot{E}}(z, t)}{\partial{z}} \ dz \end{align}$$

Using the result from above that $E(0^+, t) = E(0^-, t)$, we finally get

$$\Lambda \epsilon_0 [\dot{E}(0^-, t) - \dot{E}(0^+, t)] - \Lambda \epsilon_0 [\dot{E}(0^-,t) - \dot{E}(0^+, t)] = 0$$

But we wanted $- \Lambda \epsilon_0 \dot{E}(0, t)$, as shown in the notes above. What's going on here? Did I do something wrong?

---

### EDIT

Using the advice in the chat from the user [Eric](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/909833/eric), my new work is as follows:

$$\begin{align} \int_{0^-}^{0^+} \epsilon(z) \dot{E}(z, t) \ dz = \int_{0^-}^{0^+} \left\{ \epsilon_0 [1 + \Lambda \delta(z)] \right\} \dot{E}(z, t) \ dz \\ = \int_{0^-}^{0^+} \epsilon_0 \dot{E}(z, t) \ dz + \int_{0^-}^{0^+} \epsilon_0 \Lambda \delta(z) \dot{E}(z, t) \ dz \end{align}$$

Using the property $\int f(x) \delta(x) \ dx = f(0)$, we get that

$$\begin{align} \int_{0^-}^{0^+} \epsilon_0 \dot{E}(z, t) \ dz + \int_{0^-}^{0^+} \epsilon_0 \Lambda \delta(z) \dot{E}(z, t) \ dz = 0 + \epsilon_0 \Lambda \dot{E}(0, t) \end{align}$$

Now, we also have that

$$\int_{0^-}^{0^+} - \dfrac{\partial{H}(z, t)}{\partial{z}} \ dz = -[H(0^+, t) - H(0^-, t)]$$

So we would then have that

$$-[H(0^+, t) - H(0^-, t)] = \epsilon_0 \Lambda \dot{E}(0, t) \\ \Rightarrow H(0^+, t) - H(0^-, t) = -\epsilon_0 \Lambda \dot{E}(0, t),$$

as required.

But this leaves me with three questions:

1. Why do we have $\int_{0^-}^{0^+}$ instead of $\int_{0^+}^{0^-}$?
2. Why is $\int_{0^-}^{0^+} \dot{E}(z, t) \ dz = 0$ (or just $\int_{0^-}^{0^+} E(z, t) \ dz$)?
3. What exactly is this property $\int f(x) \delta(x) \ dx = f(0)$? Is this the Heaviside function?

Question 2 is a physics question (so I'll leave it for physics.stackexchange), but 1 and 3 are mathematics questions.

Comment: E has no discontinuities, so the difference of H over the z discontinuity at 0 is just going to be the constant in front of the Dirac spike. Your integration by parts calculation looks odd.

Comment: In particular, your integration by parts is just wrong. If you are integrating $u’v$, then you have $v$ as the E term and $u’$ as the $\epsilon$, term so you then need to have the integral of the $\epsilon$ term (aka a step function) as $u$ in the remaining portions of the equation.

Comment: @Eric Integration by parts is $${\displaystyle \int u\,dv\ =\ uv-\int v\,du}$$ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_parts With regards to $\int_{0^+}^{0^-} \epsilon(z) \dot{E}(z, t) \ dz$, I have that $\epsilon(z) = dv$ and $\dot{E}(z, t) = u$. Therefore, we have that $v = \epsilon_0 \Lambda$ and $du = \dfrac{\partial{\dot{E}(z, t)}}{\partial{z}}$.

Comment: No, $v$ is not a constant, otherwise $dv=0$.  What you need is $v=\epsilon_0(z+ \Lambda F(z))$ where $F$ is the Heaveside step function (though the z part doesn’t really matter at all, it’s the step function that’s important). This way $dv=\epsilon_0(dz +\Lamda \delta(z) dz)=\epsilon(z)dz$

Comment: @Eric Oh, ok, I see what you're saying now. Hmm, I'm not exactly sure what the problem is then. It seems to me that $\int_{0^+}^{0^-} \epsilon(z) \ dz = \int_{0^+}^{0^-} \epsilon_0[1 + \Lambda \delta(z)] = \Lambda \epsilon_0$ is valid, no? As I said, according to the Dirac Delta function properties https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function#Definitions , do we not have that $\int_{0^+}^{0^-} \delta(z) \ dz = 1$?

Comment: Yeah, but you are doing integration by parts, not just integrating the variable. Let $u=1$.  Then you get $[v]_a^b=\int^b_a v’(z) dz$. If you just integrate at a fixed point to get $v$, without letting the range be determined by $z$, then $v$ would always be a constant and the LHS would always be 0.

Comment: @Eric Hmm, so the integral of the Dirac delta function is **not** $\int_{0^+}^{0^-} \delta(z) \ dz = 1$? So we should actually have $$\int_{0^+}^{0^-} \delta(z) \ dz = H(z - 0) = H(z) = \begin{cases} 0 & \text{if} z < 0 \\ 1 & \text{if} z \ge 0 \end{cases}$$ (see here https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2136302/356308)? What exactly should we be doing here?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133003/discussion-between-eric-and-the-pointer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can answer your first and third questions3

$\boldsymbol{1:}$

This is purely a notational matter. $0^-$ is a notation that means $0$, *from the left*, so to speak. In other words we would say
$$f(0^-):=\lim_{x\to 0 \\ \text{from the left}}f(x)$$
When integrating, we like to integrate from left to right, so it makes much more sense to write $\int_{0^-}^{0^+}$ than the other way around. A more rigorous way of dealing with these kinds of integrals would be to let $a>0$ be a small positive number and consider the integrals $$\int_{-a}^{a}\epsilon(z)\dot{E}(z,t)\mathrm dz$$ And analyze the limiting case $a\to 0$.

$\boldsymbol{3:}$

I'm not sure in what capacity you've encountered the Dirac delta before, but it is *defined* as satisfying the property
$$\int_U f(x)\delta(x)\mathrm dx=f(0)$$
Where $U$ is some open set containing $0$. Formally speaking, $\delta$ is a distribution, which is a map from functions on $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ itself.

In fact, let $V$ be the real vector space of all piecewise continuous functions from $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$. (Checking that this is actually a vector space is very easy.) Then we can write very succinctly,
$$\delta\in V^*$$
Where $V^*$ is the [dual space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_space).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. With regards to 1, I understand that $0^-$ means from left/below and $0^+$ means from right/above (as more commonly seen used in the context of limits), but what confuses me is how this fits with the Riemann sum definition of definite integrals. Any chance you could add this to your answer? With regards to 3, you're right, I seem to have missed it https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function#Generalizations

Comment: @ThePointer I'm not sure what you want me to say in regards to the Riemann integral... As far as I'm aware, 
$$\int_{0^-}^{0^+}f(x)dx:=\lim_{a\to 0^-}\lim_{b\to 0^+}\int_a^bf(x)dx$$